# Unfortunately app has stopped message on restarting phone

Tags: android

My application is basically a File Manager with junk cleaner. It is working fine everywhere but when i restart my phone Unfortunately app has stopped message appears several times. Also sometimes it appears when any other application is started. Can anyone tell why it is happening, or how to detect the cause behind it.

Comment: Share your logcat...

Comment: @puneet, I think your app contains a service. So there may will be a problem where you restarting your service on bootloader. It may be due to  the time or due to the unsatisfied condition in your BroadcastReceiver or in Service class. Post logcat so that I can told you what is the exact problem.

Comment: @BalvinderSingh: Yes it was exactly the same thing, there was a service registered in manifest, but that class no longer exits. may be that was the cause. Thanks very much and ur answer is really appreciable. :)

Answer (score 0):

To detect the cause behind, you can monitor the logcat.

Since the crash occurs after the phone restart and so if you are not able to see the exception in log cat, you can log the same into a file to see the cause of exception.

Use the below link for how to log unhandled exception into file.

https://derivedcode.wordpress.com/2015/06/29/how-to-log-un-handled-exceptions-in-android/